# Exclude a sentence from punctuation grammar checking

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

Word complains about the grammar of the following sentence:

> The XML prolog is the text `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` that
>   must appear at the beginning of the document.

It wants to put a space between the question mark and "xml".

Is there a way to disable this check (or grammar checking altogether) for this particular sentence? I don't want to disable it for the entire document. Also, disabling spell checking is not sufficient and will not remove the squiggly.

[image]

Comment: At risk of sounding harsh, why not use a tool designed for the job? Word is not built to code in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the text (if can just be the prolog - you do not have to select the whole paragraph) that you do not want to check, go to Review->Language->Set Proofing Language, and check "Do not check spelling or grammar"

Comment: Huh, it worked. And I was certain I had already tried that...